# C# how to make DOS filter big files

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){


    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C" + " find" + "/v " + " \"\" " + " <" + "C:\\Users\ + "> " + "C:\\Users\\Public\\";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
```

basically trying to filter a big file. So that I could extract some of the data i dont want in the file and write it back to the new file.

Comment: That code itself is basically worthless and does pretty much nothing, give us what your actually doing.

Comment: I have re edited the post. Sorry about that. Kindly, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what your question is here.

This is some sample code. Is this what you are trying to do? If not, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

```
    var test = @"/C" + @"Find/v" + @"5Y2" + @"< C:\Users\MS.cln >" + @"C:\Users\rr277147\downloads\msvn.USE";
    Console.WriteLine(test);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It is preferable to edit your question to add the code - it can be properly formatted there.

Comment: Have you tried copying the string generated & running it from the command line to see if it works - in the code above you have a space before the v in the Find switch.